# Sign a SHA256 hash using a DER binary private key

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

Suppose you're given a binary private file that looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of binary file in Notepad++] and you know it's DER encoded.

Also, the binary file is password protected, let's say the password is 'password'

And you want to sign (RSA) an already hashed string, in other words, your data to sign is, actually, a SHA256 hash that could look like this:

```
78/YCOiMFRP66tXunCviIi/GaDvgBWFudaWnfcSkU4M=
```

And you want to do this using OpenSSL in C++.

How do we do this?

Comment: This is confusing. What is the point of showing a picture of a *binary* file in a *text* editior?

Comment: When I first encountered this problem and was given the keys, I expected the .key file to be human readable. It might help someone that doesn't fully understand what a binary file could look like. But I can remove it for you if it confuses you.

Comment: It's your question, but you should make clear **in the question itself** the relevance of anything in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be posting this here since I do not own a webpage and I think most people come here for answers.

First, we want to be able to open a password protected binary private key and be able to read its contents. With OpenSSL command line we can do this with the following line:

```
openssl pkcs8 -in binPrivateKey.key -inform DER -passin pass:password -out private.key
```

This will output the private key into the file private.key that looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKYwggSiAgEAAoIBAQCN0peKpgfOL75i
YRv1fqq+oVYsLPVUR/GibYmGKc9InHFy5lYF6OTYjnIIvmkOdRobbGlCUxORX/tL
qY9/8F5mUvVgkcczsIgGdvf9vMQPSf3jjCiKj7j6ucxl1+FwJWmbvgNmiaUR/0q4
....
h0lBer2hP8NFqBPBBTNDwQ==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

In OpenSSL there is a function called [d2i_PKCS8PrivateKey_fp](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/d2i_PKCS8PrivateKey_fp.html) wich literally takes a DER binary file pointer and outputs an internal key type, (internal for OpenSSL), which can be an EVP_PKEY, necessary for signature procedures in OpenSSL. This function can actually take a password to process the binary file. However, the password must be input via callback function, just a little tweak is necessary if we're not handling a GUI or a command line program.

The following function takes a string containing the route of the binary private key and a char pointer containing the password.

```
EVP_PKEY * PKCS8_DERtoEVP(std::string der_key_file, char * pwd){
    FILE * fp = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY * evp_pvt = NULL;
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms(); //This is necessary for some reason I do not fully understand.
    fp = fopen(der_key_file.c_str(),"rb"); //Usual file pointer of C++.
    if( fp ){
        evp_pvt = d2i_PKCS8PrivateKey_fp(fp, &evp_pvt, pwd_cb, pwd); //pwd_cb is a function callback I'll describe later.
        if (evp_pvt == NULL) {
            //ERROR HANDLING...
            fclose(fp);
            return NULL ;
            }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return evp_pvt;
}
```

The tweak I mention just in case we're not expecting any user input is the following, I'm using the standard password callback for OpenSSL:

```
int pwd_cb(char *buf, int size, int rwflag, void *u){
    char * pwd;
    if (u == NULL){
       pwd = "1234";
    } else {
       pwd = (char*)u;
    }
    size_t len = strlen(pwd);
    if (len > size) len = size;
    memcpy(buf,pwd,len);

    return len;
}
```

This way, we can 'cheat' the system into thinking the user input was the password stored in the `char` array.

Now, we're mostly ready to sign our hash. The core function to sign is the following:

```
unsigned char* signHash_DER(std::string hash_str, std::string privateKey_file, char * passphrase = NULL){
    EVP_PKEY * pkey = PKCS8_DERtoEVP(privateKey_file,passphrase);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx; //Context used in signature.
    unsigned char *sig; //The container of the signature.
    size_t siglen;
    size_t mdlen;
    if (pkey == NULL) {
        //Error handling...
        return NULL;
        }
    //Here our 'clear message' is actually our hash str and we copy it from the parameters.
    unsigned char clear_message[hash_str.length()];
    strcpy((char*) clear_message,hash_str.c_str());
    //In my implementation we require this decoding, it might not be the case for everyone.
    unsigned char * md = base64_decode(clear_message, strlen((char*) clear_message), &mdlen);
    //Initiate the context and stablish we're using default RSA.
    ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(pkey, ENGINE_get_default_RSA() /* no engine */);
    if(!ctx) {
    LOGF_ERROR("Error CTX_new");
    return NULL;
  }
  if (EVP_PKEY_sign_init(ctx) <= 0){
    //Error handling
    return NULL;
  }
 if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING) <= 0){
    //Error handling
    return NULL;
 }
 if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md(ctx, EVP_sha256()) <= 0){
    //Error handling
    return NULL;
 }
 /* Determine buffer length */
 if (EVP_PKEY_sign(ctx, NULL, &siglen, md, mdlen) <= 0){
    //Error handling
    return NULL;
 }
 sig = (unsigned char*)OPENSSL_malloc(siglen);

 if (!sig){
    //Error handling
    return NULL;
 }

 if (EVP_PKEY_sign(ctx, sig, &siglen, md, mdlen) <= 0){
    std::cout << "Error sign";
    return NULL;
 }
 /* Signature is siglen bytes written to buffer sig */
 // encode to base64 again .
 size_t signed_string_len;
 unsigned char * signed_string = base64_encode(sig, siglen, &signed_string_len);

 return signed_string;
}
```

And that's pretty much of it, most of the last function code was obtained from the OpenSSL docs, which is pretty bad tbh, but a bit of patience got the job done.

An example of a call:

```
unsigned char* signature_decoded = signHash_DER(hashed_string, "privateBinary.key","dont4get");
```

Let me know if you've any doubts, hope this helps someone!